# Detect Multibyte and Chinese Characters in rtf markup

Tags: language-agnostic, unicode, localization, rtf, multibyte

I'm trying to translate parse a RTF formatted message (I need to keep the formatting tags so I can't use the trick where you just paste into a `RichTextBox` and get the `.PlainText` out)

Take the RTF code for the string `a基bমূcΟιd` pasted straight into Wordpad:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang2057{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Calibri;}{\f1\fswiss\fcharset128 MS PGothic;}{\f2\fnil\fcharset1 Shonar Bangla;}{\f3\fswiss\fcharset161{\*\fname Arial;}Arial Greek;}}
{\*\generator Msftedit 5.41.21.2510;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\sa200\sl276\slmult1\lang9\f0\fs22 a\f1\fs24\'8a\'ee\f0\fs22 b\f2\fs24\u2478?\u2498?\f0\fs22 c\f3\fs24\'cf\'e9\f0\fs22 d\par
}
```

It's difficult to make out if you've not had much to do with RTF. So here's the bit I'm looking at

```
\'8a\'ee\f0\fs22 b\f2\fs24\u2478?\u2498?\f0\fs22 c\f3\fs24\'cf\'e9
```

Notice the `基` (`u+57FA`) is `\'8a\'ee` but the `মূ`, which is actually two characters `ম` (`\u2478?`) and `ূ` (`\u2498?`), is `\u2478?\u2498?` which is fine, but the `Οι` which is two separate characters `Ο` and `ι` is `\'cf\'e9`.

Is there a way to determine if I'm looking at something that should be one character such as `基` = `\'bb\'f9` or two characters `Ο` and `ι` = `\'cf\'e9`?

I was thinking that maybe the `\lang` was it, but that isn't the case at all because the `\lang` does not change from when it's first set. I am already accounting for the Different Codepages from different `Charset` values in the fonts, but it doesn't seem to tell me anything about if I should treat two Unicode references next to each other as being a double byte character or not.

How can I tell if the character I'm looking at should be double-byte (or multi-byte) or single byte?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\'xx` escapes represent bytes and should be interpreted using the `fcharset` encoding. (Or potentially `cchs`. Falling back to the `ansicpg` if not present.)

You need to know that encoding intimately to be able to decide whether a single `\'xx` sequence represents a character on its own or is only a part of a multi-byte character; typically you will be consuming each section of text as a unit before converting that byte string into a Unicode string using whatever library or OS interface you have available, to avoid having to write byte-by-byte parsers for every code page supported by RTF.

`\uxxxx?` escapes represent UTF-16 code units. This is much simpler, but Word[pad] only produces this form of encoding as a last resort, because it's not compatible with earlier RTF versions. (`?` is the fallback character for when the receiver can't cope with the Unicode.)

So:

- The two characters `Οι` are represented as two byte-escapes because the font associated with that stretch of text is using a Greek single-byte encoding (charset 161 = cp1253).
- The one character `基` is represented as two byte-escapes because the font associated with that stretch of text is using a Japanese multibyte encoding (charset 128 = cp932 ≈ Shift-JIS). In Shift-JIS the leading `\'8a` byte signals a further byte to come, as do various others in the top-bit-set range (but not all of them).
- The two characters `মূ` are represented as Unicode code unit escapes, because there's no other option: there isn't any RTF-compatible code page that contains Bengali characters. (Code page 57003 for ISCII came much later.)

Comment: If I know the fcharset encoding how do I use that to determine if i use single byte or double byte characters? or is there a range such as \8-\f or similar that I can use combined with the encoding to decide if i need to read the next character?

Comment: Yes, there is a range of lead-bytes that indicate a multibyte sequence, and that range differs for each multibyte encoding. See [the fcharsetN list here](http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/rtfspec_6.html) and then look up the individual code pages. For example [cp932](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/goglobal/cc305152) (≈Shift-JIS). It'll be simpler to do this by reading all the bytes in a stretch of text at once and then converting to characters using whatever existing encoding handling is available in your environment (eg Encoding in .NET), than trying to read on a byte-by-byte basis.

Comment: I wish I could vote more than once, my problem was to do with how I was re-assembling the characters on a byte-by-byte basis, I changed to read all bytes and then convert them using the .NET Encoding and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

RTF has tags for specifying the codepage/encoding used to encode Unicode characters. The actual hex codes for the characters are the byte octets used by the specified encoding. In this case, `\ansicpg1252` for Ansi codepage 1252.