# RTF conversion of escaped double-byte/multi-byte characters

Tags: python, perl, unicode, rtf, utf

Within an `RTF` file that I have (character encoding ansicp1251)

These escaped, encoded characters appear:

```
\'a1\'dd
```

When I open this in an RTF editor, it correctly opens as unicode symbol U+2265 `≥`. In the documentation for RTF, it lists these escaped characters as just being hex codes. However, it is not correct to list this as `hex(A1) + hex(DD)` because those represent two different characters, and I only want the one character of unicode U+2265 `≥`.

I have found a match for the `A1DD` within the EUC-CN = Chinese Windows = Mac OS Chinese Simplified Encoding charset, which correctly identifies unicode symbol U+2265.

However, this encoding is not listed anywhere in the file, and I'm not sure how my RTF viewer knows that I do not want `hex(A1) + hex(DD)` and I do want this double-byte character.

I have googled extensively but come up short; there are many other people with reports of this, but I have not seen a solution. I would like to write a script in Perl/Python etc. that handles this kind of conversion and not rely on the Windows tools which can read/write RTF format.

Comment: It is very hard to see what's going on w/o having the full file. There might be something in it which you overlooked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`decode($encoding, $bytes)` is used to perform this kind of conversion.

It isn't cp1251.

```
$ perl -E'
   use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-8)";
   use Encode qw( decode );
   my $bytes = join "", map chr(hex($_)), qw( a1 dd );  # "\xA1\DD"
   say sprintf "U+%v04X %1\$s", decode($ARGV[0], $bytes);
' cp1251
U+040E.042D ЎЭ
```

You'll need to fetch the correct encoding from the document. It could be euc-cn.

```
$ perl -E'
   use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-8)";
   use Encode qw( decode );
   my $bytes = join "", map chr(hex($_)), qw( a1 dd );  # "\xA1\DD"
   say sprintf "U+%v04X %1\$s", decode($ARGV[0], $bytes);
' euc-cn
U+2265 ≥
```

But it's more likely to be cp936.

```
$ perl -E'
   use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-8)";
   use Encode qw( decode );
   my $bytes = join "", map chr(hex($_)), qw( a1 dd );  # "\xA1\DD"
   say sprintf "U+%v04X %1\$s", decode($ARGV[0], $bytes);
' cp936
U+2265 ≥
```

Comment: Very interesting... it's the fcharset. With so many charsets, how do I know which one is being used for this specific piece of code?

`{\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Arial;}

{\f1\fmodern Courier New;}

{\f2\fnil\fcharset2 Symbol;}

{\f3\fmodern\fcharset0 Courier New;}

{\f4\fswiss\fcharset134 Simsun;}}`

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out.

`\htmlrtf{\f4\fs24\htmlrtf0 \'a1\'dd`

Comment: I don't know RTF but that looks like it's creating definitions that will be used later

Answer (score 3):

The encoding used for `'xx` byte escapes in RTF files varies on a font by font basis. So you'll generally have to parse the RTF enough to find the current `\fcharset` definition before being able to decide how to decode them. Here you probably have fcharset 134 aka code page 936 aka GB.

[Background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8263786)

Comment: thanks! yes it is the fcharset you are right, see below.